# invoice template: how to correct misalignment of subtotal and balance due amounts?

Tags: templates, alignment

While using the invoice template

https://www.latextemplates.com/template/invoice

the dollar amounts for the subtotal and balance due are mis-aligned with respect to the individual consulting services entry (i.e., the dots separating dollars and cents are misaligned).

How can either the latex source or the cls file be modified to align all dollar amounts in the invoice?

A simple example is the example latex file for the template, which produces the output in the link at the beginning of the post:

```
\documentclass{invoice} % Use the custom invoice class (invoice.cls)

\def \tab {\hspace*{3ex}} % Define \tab to create some horizontal white space

\begin{document}


\hfil{\Huge\bf Initech Inc.}\hfil % Company providing the invoice
\bigskip\break % Whitespace
\hrule % Horizontal line

123 Broadway \hfill (000) 111-1111 \\ % Your address and contact information
City, State 12345 \hfill john@smith.com
\\ \\
{\bf Invoice To:} \\
\tab James Smith \\ % Invoice recipient
\tab Generic Corporation \\ % Recipient's company

{\bf Date:} \\
\tab \today \\ % Invoice date


\begin{invoiceTable}

\feetype{Consulting Services} % Fee category description

\hourrow{October 3, 2012}{8}{12} 

\hourrow{October 4, 2012}{6.5}{12}

\hourrow{October 5, 2012}{5.25}{12}

\hourrow{October 10, 2012}{9.75}{20}

\hourrow{October 11, 2012}{5}{12.51}

%------------------------------------------------

\feetype{Accounting Services} % Fee category description

\hourrow{October 10, 2012}{2}{80}
\hourrow{October 11, 2012}{1}{80}

\subtotal % Prints a subtotal, can be used multiple times

%------------------------------------------------

\feetype{Hosting Expenses} % Fee category description

\feerow{Web Hosting: October, 2012}{60} % A flat fee service, note there is no hourly rate for this

\end{invoiceTable}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this special case I suggest you copy the original file `invoice.cls` into a new one and name it `myinvoice.cls`.

The reason for your culprit is that there are some `%` missing in the code for this class. That means you get insertend blank at the end of the number for subtotal you do not want. That blank is the reason for numbers not being aligned ...

Search for the code in `myinvoice.cls`:

```
\newcommand{\subtotalNoStar}{
    {\bf Subtotal} & {\bf \total{subhours} hours} &  & {\bf \$\total{subcost}}
    \setcounter{subcost}{0}
    \setcounter{subhours}{0}
    \\*[1.5ex]
}
\newcommand{\subtotalStar}{
    {\bf Subtotal} & & & {\bf \$\total{subcost}}
    \setcounter{subcost}{0}
    \\*[1.5ex]
}
```

and change it to (see `<===` for important code changings):

```
\newcommand{\subtotalNoStar}{% <====================================
    {\bf Subtotal} & {\bf \total{subhours} hours} &  & {\bf \$\total{subcost}}% <========
    \setcounter{subcost}{0}% <======================================
    \setcounter{subhours}{0}% <=====================================
    \\*[1.5ex]
}
\newcommand{\subtotalStar}{% <======================================
    {\bf Subtotal} & & & {\bf \$\total{subcost}}% <=================
    \setcounter{subcost}{0}% <======================================
    \\*[1.5ex]
}
```

So you will have a changed file `myinvoice.cls`

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  Copyright (c) 2011 Trey Hunner                                          %
%                                                                          %
%  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining   %
%  a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the         %
%  "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including     %
%  without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,     %
%  distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to      %
%  permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to   %
%  the following conditions:                                               %
%                                                                          %
%  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be          %
%  included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.         %
%                                                                          %
%  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,         %
%  EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF      %
%  MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND                   %
%  NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE  %
%  LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION  %
%  OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION   %
%  WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.         %
%                                                                          %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ProvidesClass{invoice}

\LoadClass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper,hmargin=0.79in,vmargin=0.79in]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Do not indent paragraphs
\usepackage{fp} % Fixed-point arithmetic
\usepackage{calc} % Counters for totaling hours and cost
\usepackage{longtable}

\pagestyle{empty} % No page numbers
\linespread{1.5} % Line spacing

\setlength{\doublerulesep}{\arrayrulewidth} % Double rules look like one thick one

% Command for setting a default hourly rate
\newcommand{\feetype}[1]{
    \textbf{#1}
    \\
}

% Counters for totaling up hours and dollars
\newcounter{hours} \newcounter{subhours} \newcounter{cost} \newcounter{subcost}
\setcounter{hours}{0} \setcounter{subhours}{0} \setcounter{cost}{0} \setcounter{subcost}{0}

% Formats inputed number with 2 digits after the decimal place
\newcommand*{\formatNumber}[1]{\FPround{\cost}{#1}{2}\cost} %

% Returns the total of counter
\newcommand*{\total}[1]{\FPdiv{\t}{\arabic{#1}}{1000}\formatNumber{\t}}

% Create an invoice table
\newenvironment{invoiceTable}{
    % Create a new row from title, unit quantity, unit rate, and unit name
    \newcommand*{\unitrow}[4]{%
         \addtocounter{cost}{1000 * \real{##2} * \real{##3}}%
         \addtocounter{subcost}{1000 * \real{##2} * \real{##3}}%
         ##1 & \formatNumber{##2} ##4 & \$\formatNumber{##3} & \$\FPmul{\cost}{##2}{##3}\formatNumber{\cost}%
         \\
    }
    % Create a new row from title and expense amount
    \newcommand*{\feerow}[2]{%
         \addtocounter{cost}{1000 * \real{##2}}%
         \addtocounter{subcost}{1000 * \real{##2}}%
         ##1 & & \$\formatNumber{##2} & \$\FPmul{\cost}{##2}{1}\formatNumber{\cost}%
         \\
    }

    \newcommand{\subtotalNoStar}{%
        {\bf Subtotal} & {\bf \total{subhours} hours} &  & {\bf \$\total{subcost}}%
        \setcounter{subcost}{0}%
        \setcounter{subhours}{0}%
        \\*[1.5ex]
    }
    \newcommand{\subtotalStar}{%
        {\bf Subtotal} & & & {\bf \$\total{subcost}}%
        \setcounter{subcost}{0}%
        \\*[1.5ex]
    }
    \newcommand{\subtotal}{
         \hline
         \@ifstar
         \subtotalStar%
         \subtotalNoStar%
    }

    % Create a new row from date and hours worked (use stored fee type and hourly rate)
    \newcommand*{\hourrow}[3]{%
        \addtocounter{hours}{1000 * \real{##2}}%
        \addtocounter{subhours}{1000 * \real{##2}}%
        \unitrow{##1}{##2}{##3}{hours}%
    }
    \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.8ex}
    \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
    \setlength\LTright{0pt}
    \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}\hspace{\tabcolsep}} l r r r }
    \hline
    {\bf Description of Services} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Quantity} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Unit Price} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Amount} \\*
    \hline\hline
    \endhead
}{
    \hline\hline\hline
    {\bf Balance Due} & & & {\bf \$\total{cost}} \\
    \end{longtable}
}
```

and you can use it with using the new documentclass `myinvoice` like:

```
\documentclass{myinvoice} % <===========================================

\def \tab {\hspace*{3ex}} % Define \tab to create some horizontal white space


\begin{document}

\hfil{\Huge\bf Initech Inc.}\hfil % Company providing the invoice
\bigskip\break % Whitespace
\hrule % Horizontal line

123 Broadway \hfill (000) 111-1111 \\ % Your address and contact information
City, State 12345 \hfill john@smith.com
\\ \\
{\bf Invoice To:} \\
\tab James Smith \\ % Invoice recipient
\tab Generic Corporation \\ % Recipient's company

{\bf Date:} \\
\tab \today \\ % Invoice date


\begin{invoiceTable}

\feetype{Consulting Services} % Fee category description

\hourrow{October 3, 2012}{8}{12} 

\hourrow{October 4, 2012}{6.5}{12}

\hourrow{October 5, 2012}{5.25}{12}

\hourrow{October 10, 2012}{9.75}{20}

\hourrow{October 11, 2012}{5}{12.51}

%------------------------------------------------

\feetype{Accounting Services} % Fee category description

\hourrow{October 10, 2012}{2}{80}
\hourrow{October 11, 2012}{1}{80}

\subtotal % Prints a subtotal, can be used multiple times

%------------------------------------------------

\feetype{Hosting Expenses} % Fee category description

\feerow{Web Hosting: October, 2012}{60} % A flat fee service, note there is no hourly rate for this

\end{invoiceTable}



\end{document}
```

with the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting invoice]

## Changings for aligned subtotal hours:

You need to change for `\subtotalNoStar` to (moved `hours` before number):

```
\newcommand{\subtotalNoStar}{%
    {\bf Subtotal} & {\bf hours \total{subhours}} &  & {\bf \$\total{subcost}}% <===============
    \setcounter{subcost}{0}%
    \setcounter{subhours}{0}%
    \\*[1.5ex]
}
```

and you need to change command `\unitrow` (moved `##4` before `\formatNumber{##2}`, number of used hours, to:

```
\newcommand*{\unitrow}[4]{%
     \addtocounter{cost}{1000 * \real{##2} * \real{##3}}%
     \addtocounter{subcost}{1000 * \real{##2} * \real{##3}}%
%        ##1 & \formatNumber{##2} ##4 & \$\formatNumber{##3} & \$\FPmul{\cost}{##2}{##3}\formatNumber{\cost}%
         ##1 &  ##4 \formatNumber{##2} & \$\formatNumber{##3} & \$\FPmul{\cost}{##2}{##3}\formatNumber{\cost}% <====================
```

With the changed `myinvoice.cls`

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  Copyright (c) 2011 Trey Hunner                                          %
%                                                                          %
%  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining   %
%  a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the         %
%  "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including     %
%  without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,     %
%  distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to      %
%  permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to   %
%  the following conditions:                                               %
%                                                                          %
%  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be          %
%  included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.         %
%                                                                          %
%  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,         %
%  EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF      %
%  MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND                   %
%  NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE  %
%  LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION  %
%  OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION   %
%  WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.         %
%                                                                          %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ProvidesClass{myinvoice} % <===========================================

\LoadClass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper,hmargin=0.79in,vmargin=0.79in]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Do not indent paragraphs
\usepackage{fp} % Fixed-point arithmetic
\usepackage{calc} % Counters for totaling hours and cost
\usepackage{longtable}

\pagestyle{empty} % No page numbers
\linespread{1.5} % Line spacing

\setlength{\doublerulesep}{\arrayrulewidth} % Double rules look like one thick one

% Command for setting a default hourly rate
\newcommand{\feetype}[1]{
    \textbf{#1}
    \\
}

% Counters for totaling up hours and dollars
\newcounter{hours} \newcounter{subhours} \newcounter{cost} \newcounter{subcost}
\setcounter{hours}{0} \setcounter{subhours}{0} \setcounter{cost}{0} \setcounter{subcost}{0}

% Formats inputed number with 2 digits after the decimal place
\newcommand*{\formatNumber}[1]{\FPround{\cost}{#1}{2}\cost} %

% Returns the total of counter
\newcommand*{\total}[1]{\FPdiv{\t}{\arabic{#1}}{1000}\formatNumber{\t}}

% Create an invoice table
\newenvironment{invoiceTable}{
    % Create a new row from title, unit quantity, unit rate, and unit name
    \newcommand*{\unitrow}[4]{%
         \addtocounter{cost}{1000 * \real{##2} * \real{##3}}%
         \addtocounter{subcost}{1000 * \real{##2} * \real{##3}}%
%         ##1 & \formatNumber{##2} ##4 & \$\formatNumber{##3} & \$\FPmul{\cost}{##2}{##3}\formatNumber{\cost}%
         ##1 &  ##4 \formatNumber{##2} & \$\formatNumber{##3} & \$\FPmul{\cost}{##2}{##3}\formatNumber{\cost}% <====================

         \\
    }
    % Create a new row from title and expense amount
    \newcommand*{\feerow}[2]{%
         \addtocounter{cost}{1000 * \real{##2}}%
         \addtocounter{subcost}{1000 * \real{##2}}%
         ##1 & & \$\formatNumber{##2} & \$\FPmul{\cost}{##2}{1}\formatNumber{\cost}%
         \\
    }

    \newcommand{\subtotalNoStar}{%
        {\bf Subtotal} & {\bf hours \total{subhours}} &  & {\bf \$\total{subcost}}% <===============
        \setcounter{subcost}{0}%
        \setcounter{subhours}{0}%
        \\*[1.5ex]
    }
    \newcommand{\subtotalStar}{%
        {\bf Subtotal} & & & {\bf \$\total{subcost}}%
        \setcounter{subcost}{0}%
        \\*[1.5ex]
    }
    \newcommand{\subtotal}{
         \hline
         \@ifstar
         \subtotalStar%
         \subtotalNoStar%
    }

    % Create a new row from date and hours worked (use stored fee type and hourly rate)
    \newcommand*{\hourrow}[3]{%
        \addtocounter{hours}{1000 * \real{##2}}%
        \addtocounter{subhours}{1000 * \real{##2}}%
        \unitrow{##1}{##2}{##3}{hours}%
    }
    \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.8ex}
    \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
    \setlength\LTright{0pt}
    \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}\hspace{\tabcolsep}} l r r r }
    \hline
    {\bf Description of Services} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Quantity} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Unit Price} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Amount} \\*
    \hline\hline
    \endhead
}{
    \hline\hline\hline
    {\bf Balance Due} & & & {\bf \$\total{cost}} \\
    \end{longtable}
}
```

you get with the same mwe we used before the following result:

[image: resulting pdf mwe two]

Comment: Is there a way to align this with "hours" appearing after the number?

Comment: @rhz Well, that would at last need to rewrite the complete table and add a new separate column for `hours` only. I would think about renaming `Quality` to `Hours` then you can omit hours in rows and sub total. There is -- as far as I know -- a package/class `invoice2` or simular on ctan, perhaps that does it better?

Comment: Yeah.  Changing Quantity to Hours is what I wound up doing in the end.

Comment: @rhz Can you change the class now by your own to use Hours instead Quantity? If not, please ask **a new question** containing the relevant mwe.